# What does a caret before an int mean?

Tags: go, bitwise-operators, twos-complement

I'm aware the caret symbol `^` means bitwise XOR
but I'm looking at a pice of Go code and I see things like

```
input[0] = ^output[3]
```

when I try for example:

```
^1 gives -2
^2 gives -3
etc..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the ["Arithmetic Operators"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators) section of the language specification:

> For integer operands, the unary operators +, -, and ^ are defined as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> +x                          is 0 + x
> -x    negation              is 0 - x
> ^x    bitwise complement    is m ^ x  with m = "all bits set to 1" for unsigned x
>                                       and  m = -1 for signed x
> ```

Comment: Thank you! Alexis answered first but your is more complete

Answer (score 1):

As a unary operator it means 'bitwise not'