# Why does ^1 equal -2?

Tags: go, bitwise-operators, twos-complement

```golang
fmt.Println(^1)
```

Why does this print `-2`?

Comment: You should read up on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: related: [What does a caret before an int mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307373)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^` operator is the bitwise complement operator. [Spec: Arithmetic operators:](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators)

> For integer operands, the unary operators `+`, `-`, and `^` are defined as follows:
>
> ```
> +x                          is 0 + x
> -x    negation              is 0 - x
> ^x    bitwise complement    is m ^ x  with m = "all bits set to 1" for unsigned x
>                                       and  m = -1 for signed x
> ```

So `1` in binary is a single 1 bit preceded with full of zeros:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

So the bitwise complement is a single 0 bit preceded by full of ones:

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110
```

The `^1` is an untyped constant expression. When it is passed to a function, it has to be converted to a type. Since `1` is an untyped integer [constant](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Constants), its default type `int` will be used. `int` in Go is represented using the [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) where negative numbers start with a `1`. The number being full ones is `-1`, the number being smaller by one (in binary) is `-2` etc.

The bit pattern above is the 2's complement representation of `-2`.

To print the bit patterns and type, use this code:

```
fmt.Println(^1)
fmt.Printf("%T\n", ^1)
fmt.Printf("%064b\n", 1)
i := ^1
fmt.Printf("%064b\n", uint(i))
```

It outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/-EgWsTgy12F)):

```
-2
int
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this has to do with the way that we use signed signs in computation.

For a 1 byte number, you can get

| D | B |
| --- | --- |
| -8 | 1000 |
| -7 | 1001 |
| -6 | 1010 |
| -5 | 1011 |
| -4 | 1100 |
| -3 | 1101 |
| -2 | 1110 |
| -1 | 1111 |
| 0 | 0000 |
| 1 | 0001 |
| 2 | 0010 |
| 3 | 0011 |
| 4 | 0100 |
| 5 | 0101 |
| 6 | 0110 |
| 7 | 0111 |

You can see here that 1 is equivalent to 0001 (Nothing changes) but -1 is equal to 1111. `^` operator does a bitwise xor operation. Therefore:

```
0001
1111 xor
-------
1110 -> That is actually -2.
```

All this is because of the convention of [two complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) that we use to do calculations with negative numbers. Of course, this can be extrapolated to longer binary numbers.

You can test this by using windows calculator to do a xor bitwise calculation.